# certain levels of categorical variables insignificant

Tags: r, linear-regression

I was working on a multiple regression model that predicts amount of insurance claims based on certain factors. One such (categorical) factor is the room type the person has access to as part of the insurance package (eg. VIP room). The problem is   that a few room types have a high variability in claims which results in them being insignificant predictors (p value as high as 0.6 for those levels). My suggestion is to create two separate models, one with room type as a predictor and one without. If a person is part of one of the rooms with high variability then the model without room type as a predictor should be used otherwise the better fit model can be used (has a higher adjusted R^2).

My question is, is there something incorrect with this procedure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many possible types of rooms you have there, but it can be that some categories have a very low volume compared to the others. If that's the case, I'd rather try to combine types with similar characteristics as new categories. That may increase volume and make them significant.

It's hard to suggest things without seeing the data.